# What's a simple way to create a transparent proxy over SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, ssl, nginx

I have a remote computer that I connect to via SSH that I want to proxy certain domains through the connecting client's network.

I figured setting up a simple proxy (like nginx) on the client and using a reverse SSH tunnel should be enough - but have had no luck and am now wondering if it's possible.

My plan was to:

- Connect to my remote with `ssh user@remote.example.com -R 443:localhost:443`.
- The remote will have entries in its `/etc/hosts`, looping back certain domains

```
service-1.example.com 127.0.0.1
service-2.example.com 127.0.0.1
```

- Proxy on the client will receive those requests and proxy them based on the `Host` header.

Didn't go to plan:

Initially I thought it would as simple as setting up nginx with a proxy_pass/reverse proxy however that doesn't forward the SSL stuff, requiring self signed certificates.

I looked into adding a module like [proxy_connect_module](https://github.com/chobits/ngx_http_proxy_connect_module) but I have been struggling to compile nginx at all (MacOS), spending hours on trying to figure out what version of the source to get, where to get it from, what version of OpenSSL, pcre, gcc, clang, etc - in the end I got nowhere with it.

I am not even sure also don't know if this is even what I need?

Any idea what the easiest way to achieve this is?

Answer (score 2):

> Initially I thought it would as simple as setting up nginx with a proxy_pass/reverse proxy however that doesn't forward the SSL stuff, requiring self signed certificates.

You can't forward the SSL stuff based on the "Host:" header, because the "Host:" header is inside the SSL (TLS) connection and cannot be seen by the proxy unless the proxy terminates and decrypts SSL.

It's impossible to both decrypt the traffic and keep the original server's certificate intact; it's pretty much *the job* of SSL and TLS to make this impossible.

Instead, you need a proxy that forwards connections based on the TLS SNI (Server Name Indication) extension. sniproxy and HAproxy are two options.

(An HTTP CONNECT proxy would be *non*-transparent, as it requires the client to explicitly send an HTTP CONNECT request specifying the target host:port.)

Comment: OH that's right, I completely forgot about that. I'm exploring TinyProxy - does that sound suitable?

Comment: TinyProxy is still an HTTP/HTTPS proxy, so it'll have exactly the same issues as Nginx proxy_pass.

Comment: @DavidAlsh you are not going to be able to do this in user space (ie using a proxy server).  You may well be able to use NAT (ie iptables) to rewrite the source and destination - but I suspect that you will have difficulties because you are routing to rather then through the jumphost.

Comment: @davidgo: That's already taken care of by OP's /etc/hosts entries.

Comment: Another thing to explore is using SSH as a SOCKS proxy - this will, however, require configuration changes in your web browser, so it won't be transparent. See https://thinkingeek.com/2022/01/03/ssh-and-socks/

Comment: @user1686 No, I don't think it is.  Those entries will route the traffic to the local machine, and through SSH, but I don't know that it is possible (using iptables) to forward that traffic on the remote server because the destination is localhost - so it won't go through the PREROUTING or FORWARDING tables, so the addresses can't be rewritten with that.

Comment: @davidgo: They'll route the traffic to the SSH tunnel listener on :443 on the local machine, which forwards everything to the proxy listening on the remote end of the SSH connection.

Comment: @user1686 Agreed.  We are talking cross purposes but what I was thinking of would not work either as it assumes all the remote sites they are trying to reach are on the same (remote) IP address, which is likely not the case.

Comment: @user1686 - Would using NGINX with non terminating, TLS Passthrough work for the remote end?  (https://www.mybluelinux.com/nginx-tls-sni-routing-based-on-subdomain-pattern/ )  That seems to me to use SNI to get the host name to proxy to - so doesn't use the header field or terminate the TLS connection.

Comment: @davidgo: They don't have to be on the same address – the proxy can be configured to forward requests to the correct destination (either preconfigured IPs or possibly making its own DNS lookups); that's the whole purpose of sniproxy here (i.e. routing different domains by TLS SNI). Yes, nginx would work if it can do the same TLS inspection.

Comment: @user1686 - totally missed that part of your answer.